# Limit/Secure Google Appengine servlet (REST service provider) to be consumed by a specific mobile app

Tags: android, ios, security, google-app-engine, appcelerator-mobile

What is the best solution to secure a REST service provider (assume a java servlet running on google appengine) by allowing requests only from iOS or Android device from a specific app?

Assume I have a servlet running on google appengine that does some processing and responds to a GET request with some JSON data. And I want to restrict this access to my app that runs on Android and iOS.

My current solutions are:

1. Use `if(tokenValue ==
   request.getHeader(tokenKey))` on the
   appengine servlet. And
   `response.addHeader(tokenKey,
   tokenValue)` on the mobile apps'
   code. So basically only my app would
   know the token key.
2. Use [HTTP(s)](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Secure_URLs) for the above solution, appengine supports this
3. Use [oAuth](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/overview.html) - but I need to have the user sign-on to some oAuth provider from the app, which complicates the app

Suggest other useful approaches to tackle this problem. Assume this servlet only serves GET requests and maybe use Restlet or Jackson

Answer (score 0):

Only 3 would be an appropriate solution if security is important to you. This is because anyone using the application can intercept the traffic and just replay the values against your web service. SSL offers some protection but a good attacker can work out how to capture data if they control the device. With OAuth the damage done by an attacker is limited to a single user (as long as they are not an app admin).

Comment: Well, security is not exactly the primary concern. I just don't want other users to consume my REST service. So how would I implement solution#3 without having the iphone or android user to authenticate to a an oAuth provider?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a client SSL certificate?  I haven't tried this, but I'm considering it.  Here's a page that describes the approach, with some sample code:
http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html

Comment: Unfortunately google app engine doesn't support client side certificates. They also hide the ball on this one - the only mention is an oblique one here:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Security_and_Authentication

("App Engine does not support custom security roles (<security-role>) or alternate authentication mechanisms (<login-config>) in the deployment descriptor."